# blocking referring domain and all of its subdomains via rewrites in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking to block two referrers along with all of their subdomains.  When using this in my htaccess, they're not getting a 403, but instead a 500 response from apache (complaining about too many internal redirects) so i'm wondering why its causing that

Here is the code i'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*domain2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

The referrers are coming through as:

```
http://sub.domain.com/page.php?u=http://example.com
```

(they have multiple subdomains.. always changing.. the example.com above is my domain)

Basically, they're littering my google analytics w/ fake referrals - so i want to block them from showing up.

Here's the error from the apache log:
    Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Comment: Your rules look fine to me, so I'm not sure what's causing the 500 error.  You'll probably need to set `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel 3` or higher, then plow through the rewrite log messages to see what's going wrong.